# Angular authentication with django rest framework

Tags: angular, django-rest-framework

I'm using django-rest-framework to create a api for my Front-end, but now i having problem with the authentication, i can't find some guide to do this.

Can i use angular in my Front-end to authenticate my users that are already in my django User model.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use Django's backend authentication system.

You can **create one middle ware** to check user's authentication for token from db (Token table) or Session (Authenticated User). It depends on you which authentication system you want to use.

If user is not authenticated then **redirect them to login url**.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is too late to answer this question but recently I have created my first Angular 7 based project with Django 2.1 which actually helped me understanding "how to use Angular".

The [project](https://github.com/RaiVaibhav/beer-review-platform) uses [django-rest-auth](https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth) ( you can check the documentation where they mention about customizing the User Model ) and 
[django-rest-framework-jwt](https://github.com/jpadilla/django-rest-framework-jwt)
for authentication using jwt.